# Accessing Ubuntu guest on Windows?

Tags: networking, postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu in WSL version 1, installed pgAdmin4 in Ubuntu, and since there is no browser (it is just a terminal), I want to access pgAdmin through a Windows browser.

The subsystem and my Windows host both have the same local ip-address `192.168.1.102`. However, when I try to go to 192.168.1.102/pgadmin4 in my browser, it says that the page cannot be reached. Any idea what is wrong? I have postgreSQL started as well.

Note: I installed pgAdmin4 on my subsystem by following the guide at https://websiteforstudents.com/install-postgresql-server-11-and-manage-it-with-pgadmin4-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-18-10/

Comment: Well, it is the other way around - I have a Ubuntu subsystem on Windows, not Windows subsystem on Ubuntu. Anyways, I have WSL version 1 :)

Comment: Ubuntu on WSL knows very little about Windows.  You will need to install a browser in ubuntu but you will need an X server first then install firefox or chromium in ubuntu.